# iPhone Browser: Disable page scroll while dragging html input field

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

I have made a HTML page. This page is smaller than Iphone screen. Let's say this is login page. The page contains text input fields.

I disabled scrolling the page this way:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

That code prevents scrolling, but when I tap an input field and drag, than the page is scrolling anyway.

Is there a way to completely disable page scrolling in HTML at iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me

```js
$("body").bind("touchmove", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The user can always scroll to the top by touching the status bar, so the best way to prevent scrolling is to keep scrolling. Put `window.scrollTo(x, y)` in a `setInterval`, and whenever the user scroll the page you can scroll it back to the right position.

When the user click on an input field, Mobile Safari might scroll up a bit to avoid keyboard covering the input field. Make sure that you scrolling behavior won't get the input field covered by the keyboard.